# Can i change existing SharePoint sql connection from hostname to fqdn?

Tags: sharepoint-server

We are currently using sql server hostname and instance name for connecting the SharePoint farm to SQL database instance.
e.g: sqlserver1\instance1

Now we are required to use the sql fqdn name instead of host name like sqlserver.domain.com\instance1.

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Renaming SQL for SP is problematic, but there is great workaround for it and it is best practice for configuration anyway.

User server alias to point it to the FQDN. Set alias to sqlserver to sqlserver.domain.com (as you use instace name in config that should suffice)

To run the server alias console run the cliconfg from the run console on the server.

Step by step details can be found here:
https://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=255

Comment: thanks for response. I can use alias configuration for sql fqdn but how can i change the new alias configuration for existing sharepoint farm. I think farm rebuild is needed for this. Please clarify,

Comment: No rebuild is not necessary, you can even switch to different server using this method. But remember to set it up for all SP servers. What you effective do is to tell any sofware running on the server to resolve serverA to AliasB. So nothing in your Sharepoint config changes.

Comment: how can i change the existing config db connecting string. I think these admin/config db connection string would be set up during the initial farm configuration itself.  Can you please share any reference links on setting up aliases for existing farm?

Comment: You don't change it. You just redirect the traffic to new Target using server Alias. I updated the answer with step by step example from Todd Klindt.